# File Writing Python, How to print variable to txt file

Tags: python, sos, file-writing

I am trying to print a variable of a score and name to a .txt file using python.

```
import random
import csv
import operator
import datetime


now = datetime.datetime.now() ## gets the exact time of when the user begins the test.

def main():
    global myRecord
    myRecord = []
    name = getNames()
    myRecord.append(name)
    record = quiz()


def getNames(): ## this function grabs first and lastname of the user
    firstName = input ("Please enter your first name") ## asks for users name
    surName = input("Please enter your surname") ## asks for users suername
    space = " "
    fullName =  firstName + space +surName ## puts data of name together to  make full name
    print("Hello")
    print (fullName)
    myRecord.append(fullName)
    return fullName ## this is a variable returned to main

def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0 ## sets score to 0.
    for i in range(10): ## repeats question 10 times
        correct = askQuestion()## if the statement above if correct the program asks a question.
        if correct:
            score += 1## adds one to the score
            print('Correct!\n')## prints correct if the user gets a question correct.
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n') ## prints incorrect if the user gets a question wrong.
            return 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add, ## selects one of the three operators
           '-':operator.sub, ## selects one of the three operators
           '*':operator.mul,} ## selects one of the three operators
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)    ## samples a number between 0 and 12
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)   ## zero are not used to stop diving by zero
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))  ## puts together the num1, the operator and num2 to form question
    return answer

def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def myfileWrite (myrecord):
    with open('Namescore.txt', 'w') as score:
        score.write(fullName + '\n')




main()
```

here is the full code it should ask the users name, print 10 maths questions and then save the time name and score to a txt file
 if you can help please do
many thanks

Comment: your last edit removed all code from the question. You should not do this as now it is impossible to understand what your question was about in the first instance

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect and you never actually call the function:

```
with open('Namescore.txt', 'w') as score:
    score.write(fullName + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you wrote would IIRC re-make the file each time you ran the code. I believe this is the correct way to do it:

```
with open("Namescore.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(name, score, "\n")  # I don't know what your vars are called
```

This will append to the file rather than rewrite :)

If you want to do it your way, the correct way would be:

```
def writeScore(name, score):
    file = open("Namescore.txt", "a")
    file.write(name, score, "\n")
    file.close()

writeScore("Example Examlpus", 201)
```